# UTF-8 character gets changed in INSERT statement on MS-SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode, utf-8

I have a table on my MS-SQL-Server 2008R2 that itself has an `nvarchar(50)` field.

Now when i insert a value using the Server Management Studio like

```
INSERT INTO INFORMATIONS(SOME_TEXT) VALUES('finančné služby')
```

and i immediately select the value

```
SELECT SOME_TEXT FROM INFORMATIONS
```

i get

```
financné služby
```

So the `č`does get converted into a plain `c` while the `ž` is handled just fine.

What am I missing here?

The collation is set to `Latin1_General_CI_AS` if that is of any help.

Comment: You mean the `ž` is handled just fine, right?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Prefix your values with **N** while inserting.

```
INSERT INTO INFORMATIONS(SOME_TEXT) VALUES(N'finančné služby')
```

[**CHECK SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3c03/1)

Comment: When I try this I get the same thing, it changes the characters (on sql 2012)

Comment: This works, but why? I'd like to get some explanation

Comment: @Nikola I think N means native, therefore supporting those characters.

Comment: In the 2008R2 version of the server, [`char` and `varchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms176089(v=sql.105)) hold non-unicode characters, while [`nchar` and `nvarchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186939(v=sql.105)) hold unicode characters. The 'N' character before a string states that it must be treated as unicode characters. In newest version of MSSQL, check documentation, because the four type of fields have changed behaviour.

Comment: Man su saved my life. I was struggling with python insert on SQL Server 2008R2. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are **working with stored procedure** then give type **'Nvarchar' instead of Varchar** of that particular filed on that you will store UTF-8 characters

Answer (score 0):

Add **N** with the with string

```
  insert into Item_Registration ([fırstlan_arabic],[second_turkish])values(N'قهوة شوكو',N'قهوة شوكو')
```

[image]

ıf you are usıng C# or vb.net and Sqlcommand for inserting utf character you can use `SqlDbtype.NText` data type

```
CMD = New SqlCommand(cb)
 CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d11", SqlDbType.NText).Value =
                    If(txt_name_secondlan.Text = "", "''", txt_name_secondlan.Text)
```